# Installed Ubuntu on LG Gram 17 but not able to boot

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, uefi

I've "successfully" installed Ubuntu on my LG Gram, however I'm not able to boot from Ubuntu. I've tried different things without success, and maybe you can point me to the right direction or give me better instructions on how to proceed.
This is how my disks look now:

[image: Gra]

As you can see C: is for Windows 10. Then I think there is something to boot from Ubuntu, then 216G for Ubuntu. Which means the Ubuntu install did work. I'm not able to run Ubuntu even using the advanced startup options from Windows.

Many thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm  answering my own question because now I'm writing from my Ubuntu Installation without any issues.

**Steps after installing Ubuntu but without being able to boot**

What I did was really simple. I started Ubuntu with a bootable Ubuntu USB (using Rufus with all defaults) and choose *Try Ubuntu*, then I installed **boot-repair** (you can google this one easily) and follow every step to repair the boot, overwriting the GRUB as far as I know. Inside **boot-repair** I chose the default option, not the advanced one, and everything went well.

**Advice for installing Ubuntu**

One more thing, to those who are not installed Ubuntu yet on their LG Gram. You have to change your EUFI settings following this instructions https://github.com/crazyluv/solve-lg-gram-17-linux-boot-error otherwise you will probably see a flood of errors and Ubuntu will stop working suddenly.

**In case you can't boot with your bootable USB**

If you are seeing this message when trying to boot from USB `efi/boot/null not found` disable secure boot, enable legacy OS support, and try to install Ubuntu right after you save your UEFI configuration.

Hope this helps!