# Unable to boot using Fedora Live USB on LG Gram 17

Tags: ubuntu, multi-boot, fedora, uefi

I am trying to install Fedora 31 on my LG Gram 17. I was able to boot originally through a Live USB created using Fedora media writer once i disabled the secure boot option in the bios.
My existing SSD did not have enough space and hence i upgraded to a larger NVME drive (Samsung 970 Evo Plus 1 TB if it helps) recently. Post upgrading, the live USB stopped booting with the below error:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\NULL - Not found
Failed to load \EFI\BOOT\NULL: Not found 
start_image() returned Not Found
```

I have tried generating the live USB boot disk through Rufus also. Still no joy.
Have tried the same with Ubuntu live USB and get the same error.

I understand this is very similar to the below thread:
[Installed Ubuntu on LG Gram 17 but not able to boot](https://superuser.com/questions/1505942/installed-ubuntu-on-lg-gram-17-but-not-able-to-boot)

There is mention of "*enable legacy OS support*" on the BIOS but I could not find this option.

I have so far:

1. Secure boot option - Disabled
2. Delete All signatures - Done

Is there anything else I need doing?

Comment: Try this : https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1645125#p1645125

Answer (score 1):

Obtained from [this Korean blog](https://blog.1day1.org/596):

Inside the USB drive go to `\EFI\BOOT\`, copy `grubx64.efi` and rename the copy to `NULL` (not `NULL.efi` but simply `NULL`)

It worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me, too. --LG gram 17"